# No space under communities section in profile

Tags: bug, design, user-interface

The communities section under profile, when empty, the empty state doesn't have space after the heading. This happens throughout the Stack Exchange network.

[image: communities]

This happens everywhere.

**Update:** I am unable to find this where it happens. Could even be a loading part. How did this come in BTW?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog Someone's faster than me! 